# Script causing div to blink when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am learning JavaScript. I created a navigation bar with two divs:

[image]

And added a function so that when the user scrolls down, the first div will fadeOut:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $nav = $('.first-nav'); //Caching element

  // fade in .navbar
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      // set distance user needs to scroll before we start fadeIn
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 275) {
        $nav.fadeOut("fast");
      } else {
        $nav.fadeIn();
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top pages">
  <div class="container-fluid first-nav">
    <button id="nav-toggle" data-target=".sidebar-right" data-toggle="sidebar" class="navbar-toggle toggle-right" type="button">
        <span></span>
        </button>
    <a href="" id="login-button">Login</a>
    <a href="/#get_quote"><button id="get_quote_navbar" name="get_quote_navbar" class="btn btn-login">Get Quote</button></a>
    <a href="tel:8774000232" class="phone-number-link"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (877) 400-0232</a>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand" id="brand-desktop"></a>
    <!-- /Logo -->
    <a href="" id="nav-desktop">Home</a>
    <a href="" id="nav-desktop">For Home</a>
    <a href="" id="nav-desktop">For Business</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navigation" class="col-md-12 sub-nav">
    <div class="col-md-6 sub-nav-left">
      <a href="" id="sub-left">Commercial</a>
      <a href="" id="sub-left">Construction</a>
      <a href="" id="sub-left">Multy-family</a>
      <a href="" id="sub-left">Partnership</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 sub-nav-right">
      <a href="/#get_quote"><button id="get_quote" name="get_quote_navbar" class="btn btn-quote">Get Quote</button></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

All works fine. In CSS, I created @media for min and max width. And when I do that, for desktop and tablet is all good, but when I want to put fixed first div for mobile, JavaScript makes a problem and I have blinked div when scroll up-down.

How I can add in JS function `if (width < 1024) then $nav.fadeIn();`?

Comment: Your question's title is not about what you are looking for.

Comment: It's edited. And I find solution: 
`if ($(this).scrollTop() > 275 && $(window).width() > 1024) { `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I succeeded. This is a code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $nav = $('.first-nav');//Caching element
        // hide .navbar first - you can also do this in css .nav{display:none;}

        // fade in .navbar
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 275 && $(window).width() > 1024) { 
                    $nav.fadeOut("fast");
                } else {
                    $nav.fadeIn();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    $nav.fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I add this in my function request and all is good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with media queries in javaScript, just use the `window.matchMedia()` as following:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
    /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
    /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

Full reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

To get the effect  on resizing the window, you need to do like:

```
function foo(){
    //code here
}
foo();
$(window).on('resize orientationchange',foo);
```

Comment: You can even use `addListener` method to `window.matchMedia` for resize and orientation change which would be better than binding to `window` object, .g see: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/

Comment: Can you please tell me about that..?

Comment: Here is the doc about method i'm talking about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this for test the with of the window,

> note: you have to refresh the page when you change the size of the window

```
  var widthScreen = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1023px)').matches;
  if(widthScreen){
      $nav.fadeIn();
  }
```